# What version of R should I use to upgrade R in ubuntu 15.04

Tags: r, ubuntu

The codename (version name) of my ubuntu 15.04 is 'vivid'. But there is no such version is available in the CRAN.[(Resource Location for R)](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/) What version should I install among  available versions(they are precise, testy, xenial, yakety, and zesty) for ubuntu 15.04. The version of R I installed is (R version) 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) -- "Pumpkin Helmet".

Comment: I imagine you'd want Trusty, since it's the most recent supported release (I'm assuming 15.04 can run something built for 14.XX). Otherwise you could try Vivid which is not longer supported, but built for 15.04.

Comment: Have you tried `deb https://<my.favorite.cran.mirror>/bin/linux/ubuntu vivid/`? I know it's not listed

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04 had its end of life in February 2016. Consider updating your system.

Comment: Yes, I had tried this way but didn't  work. I will try once more tomorrow.

Comment: @Dason I will update the system. Right now I don't have options to backup my data. I am not sure when I can update the system. Do you think I can't run R in 15.04?

Comment: You can. I'm just saying that updating R seems like less of a concern than updating the system itself. And when you do update consider going with a LTS release if you plan on using the system for longer than the 9 months that non-LTS releases are supported.

Comment: @Mako212,@Dason:  I am able to install with 'trusty'. Thank you very much for being helpful.

Answer (score 0):

versions of R for different versions of ubuntu are as given below.

Ubuntu 12.04: precise
Ubuntu 14.04: trusty
Ubuntu 16.04: xenial

I have got the answer from this wonderful  [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GsuA5ugYqyw). I highly recommend to watch the video if you have to install and/or upgrade R.